# PHP streams: difference between options and parameters

Tags: php

Two key concepts in the [PHP streams](http://php.net/streams) feature are [context options and parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php). **What is the difference between «option» and «parameter»?**

[Documentation about the former](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php) is fairly straightforward. It seems an *option* is a protocol specific setting, e.g. "method" (get, post, put...) if you are using HTTP or "callback function to be called when inserting a document" in MongoDB.

What's a *parameter* then? The [`stream_context_set_params()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-params.php) contains a sparse reference to *Supported parameters* being "notification" and "options" (options??). The [Context parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/context.params.php) page only mentions "notification", as if they had great plans for the future when PHP/4.3.0 was released but they never bloomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

I did some research and found out, that the code is really old, it was introduced by commit [`e1d0a1479`](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/e1d0a147901d27bb01b0ccda315a9fdd3474e1ee) and kept more or less unchanged since that time. (2003/04/10)

The author of this code was *Wez Furlong*. I would ask him, since I fear that nobody can provide a better answer. (Find his email address on [github](https://github.com/wez))

---

IMHO parameters ([there is only one atm](http://php.net/manual/en/context.params.php)), can be used for all context wrappers where options are specific for a certain type of wrapper.

Actually you can set *two* different parameters with `stream_context_set_params()`: `notification` (as named above) and (this might be suprising) `options` which is an assoc array with options that could be also set using `stream_context_set_options()`.

It looks like the `stream_context_set_params()` function is a more generic attempt, however I still don't get the advantage of that concept completely atm.. Would need to have a look at the code and the commit history.

Comment: Some answers deserve that upvotes would count triple :)

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you that the current implementation (and it's documentation) looks a bit weird at this point. Good catch, and thanks for pointing this out here! My best guess would be that the *params* facility was originally planned to get something bigger, but then was never touched again. That's open source! As long as nobody cares, nothing changes. ;) . I would really like to hear Wez' reasoning behind that! I'm sure he had his reasons.